# Как правильно использовать квадратные скобки в SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Допустим, есть база данных с нижеследующими строками:

```
SELECT * FROM clients;
+----+------------+------+----------------------+----------+--------+
| id | date       | name | email                | city     | code   |
+----+------------+------+----------------------+----------+--------+
|  1 | 2007-10-18 | John | john445@gmail.com    | London   |  23345 |
|  2 | 2010-05-21 | Anna | meow98@yahoo.com     | Milan    |  21785 |
|  3 | 2015-05-03 | Kate | dream21@gmail.com    | New York |  51290 |
|  4 | 2009-06-02 | Mike | hamster_1@gmail.com  | New York | 991334 |
|  5 | 2003-04-19 | Stan | stan39_fr@gmail.ru   | Lyon     |  34521 |
+----+------------+------+----------------------+----------+--------+
```

Следующий запрос выводит пустое значение:

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE city LIKE '[LN]%';
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти причину, по которой не удается получить нужные строки. Может проблема в версии MySQL (используется 5.6) или я некорректно составил запрос?

Comment: А зачем вам квадратные скобки? Может это какой-то хитрый элемент поиска в MySql? По факту если брать просто SQL то вы ищете все города, которые начинаются на [LN], судя по запросу. А что вы хотите получить в итоге?

Comment: По правде говоря я прохожу обучение по использованию SQL. В нем приводятся примеры того, как можно искать строки по шаблону при помощи квадратных скобок.

Например, по диапазону символов [a-z], по наличию букв [abc] или исключая их [^abc]. Но все эти примеры у меня не заработали, хотя в Интернете пишут, что все должно работать. Выясняю почему.

И Вы правы. Этот запрос ищет  любые города на L и N.

Comment: Ну поиск с использованием функции `REGEXP_LIKE` видел. А вот такой поиск - нет. Ну опыта в MySql мало по фаакту у меня. Можете привести пример, где пишут что должно работать?

Comment: Такое не сработает `SELECT * FROM clients WHERE city LIKE 'L%' OR city LIKE 'N%' ;`?

Comment: Нужно использовать не LIKE, а RLIKE. Т.е. запрос `SELECT * FROM clients WHERE city RLIKE '[LN]'` вернет строки, у которых значение в поле city содержит хотя бы один из символов, перечисленных в квадратных скобках. А запрос `SELECT * FROM clients WHERE city RLIKE '^[LN]'` вернет строки, у которых поле city начинается на L или N.

Comment: Или строить паттерн, используя `REGEXP` вместо `like` http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-regular-expression-regexp.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следует использовать RLIKE и знак % внутри квадратных скобок.

Например:

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE city RLIKE 'L[oy%]n';
+----+------------+------+-------------------+--------+-------+
| id | date       | name | email             | city   | code  |
+----+------------+------+-------------------+--------+-------+
|  1 | 2007-10-18 | John | john445@gmail.com | London | 23345 |
+----+------------+------+-------------------+--------+-------+
```

Или:

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE city RLIKE 'L[oy%]';
+----+------------+------+--------------------+--------+-------+
| id | date       | name | email              | city   | code  |
+----+------------+------+--------------------+--------+-------+
|  1 | 2007-10-18 | John | john445@gmail.com  | London | 23345 |
|  5 | 2003-04-19 | Stan | stan39_fr@gmail.ru | Lyon   | 34521 |
+----+------------+------+--------------------+--------+-------+
```

Дополнительную информацию и примеры, можно получить в режиме консоли, используя команды:

```
mysql> HELP 'LIKE'
mysql> HELP 'RLIKE'
```

Comment: и использовать `RLIKE`

Comment: Спасибо :) Исправил!